# LINQ query retrieves whole record instead of one field

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this C# L2S code:

```
Table<ERPRaw> linqRawFile = db.GetTable<RawFile>();
var linqNameList =
    from row in linqRawFile.AsEnumerable()
    select row.fileName;
currentFileNameList = linqNameList.ToArray();
```

It's supposed to read only the fileName field, but when I check in the SQL server profiler, I see that this query triggers full record loading. The fields contain file binary data, so the full table loading takes considerable time. Retrieving just the fileName field takes only few milliseconds.

What would be the right way to retrieve only fileName field of RawFile in as an array of strings? I assume that the linq framework now loads each RawFile record in full, as it doesn't see I will retrieve only the fileName property from the list.

Perhaps I have to construct the query without referencing the linqRawFile at all? Wouldn't that be kind of ignoring the reason linq is introduced in the project, to abstract the database layer away?

Comment: Probably due to `.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: `var linqNameList = (from row in linqRawFile select row.fileName).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's supposed to read only the fileName field

No, it does not. Here is what is going on: your query execution happens in two places - in RDBMS and in memory. The `db.GetTable<RawFile>()` happens in RDBMS; everything after it happens in memory, because you use `AsEnumerable()`.

The portion of the query where the projection happens (i.e. `row.fileName` column is extracted from the whole row) is happening in memory. The RDBMS part of the query does not know about this projection. `db.GetTable<RawFile>()` is all the SQL-generating LINQ provider sees, so naturally it returns the entire row.

If you write a combined query against your SQL source, the projection will happen in SQL:

```
var linqNameList =
    from row in db.GetTable<RawFile>()
    select row.fileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace the whole thing with this:

```
var currentFileNameList = db.GetTable<RawFile>().Select(r => r.fileName).ToArray();
```